# Ensure element is exist in the page, to ensure is logged in or any other action

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, apify

I'm using puppeteer, node js I'm writing a script to log in it successfully logged, but I need to write code to ensure it successfully logged in by ensure some element is present, I need to write if element is present focused on it or if it not present print "element is not present".

This the script I've written:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function log_in() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--Window-size=1929,1170', '--Window-position=0,0']
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ 'width': 1366, 'height': 768 });
    await page.goto(URL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    await page.click('.fancybox-item');
    await delay(1000);

    // fun for waiting 
    function delay(time) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(resolve, time)
        });
    }

    const UserName = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    const Password = '222222';

    page.click('selector');
    await delay(1000);
    //Focus on user name 
    await page.focus('selector');
    await delay(2000);
    await page.type('selector', UserName);
    await delay(2000);
    //Focus on password 
    await page.focus('selector');
    await page.type('selector'', Password);

    // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
    page.click('selector');
    await delay(5000);
   
    if (await page.waitForSelector('selector')) {
       console.log("found")
    } else console.log("not found");
    await delay(5000);
} log_in();
```

Note: the code is work successfully but it doesn't print anything in console output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [page.$(selector)](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pageselector). It returns an element or null if no matches the selector. And you need to wait for navigation after you click on submit button using [page.waitForNavigation([options])](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions) probably.

```
...
// Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
await page.click('selector')
await page.waitForNavigation()

const element = await page.$('selector')

if (element) {
    console.log ('found')
} else {
    console.log ('not found')
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm afraid you have lacks experience in working with asynchronous Javascript. It's crucial to understand this concept since most of the functions of Puppeteer is async. The same other libraries or tools like Selenium.

Try to learn more about that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Answering on your problem: I think it'd be to use `waitForSelector()` instead of `document.querySelector` (`page.$`) as @drobnikj suggested. First of all `waitForSelector()` waits for the element so you can handle elements that might load asynchronously. It might not be the case on your page but in general, it's a better approach I believe. All that you need to do is to handle a potential exception.

My proposition is:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--Window-size=1929,1170', '--Window-position=0,0']
    });

const page = await browser.newPage()[0];

async function logIn(loginPageUrl, userName, password) {
  const fancyBoxItemSelector = '.fancybox-item';
  const loginInputSelector = '';
  const passwordInputSelector = '';
  const loginRedirectionLink = '';

  const expectedSelectorAfterLogin = '';

  await page.goto(URL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

  await page.waitForSelector(fancyBoxItemSelector);
  await page.click(fancyBoxItemSelector);

  await page.waitForSelector(loginInputSelector);
  await page.click(loginInputSelector);
  await page.type(loginInputSelector, userName);

  await page.waitForSelector(passwordInputSelector);
  await page.click(passwordInputSelector);
  await page.type(passwordInputSelector, password);

  await page.waitForSelector(loginRedirectionLink);

  const response = page.waitForNavitation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
  await page.click(loginRedirectionLink);
  await response;

  try {
    await page.waitForSelector(expectedSelectorAfterLogin);
    console.log('Selector found!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Selector not found!');
  }
}

(async () => {
   await logIn('', '', '')
})()
```

I allowed myself to polish your code. I hope it's clear what I have done here.